# .apk file getting installed as .zip from my web server

Tags: installation, zip, apk, shared-hosting

I am serving an apk via my shared hosting server, but when users navigate to the link and downloads the .apk it gets downloaded as an .zip on various devices. How can I ensure that it gets downloaded as an .apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

Create an index.php in a folder which contains:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['apk'])) { header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<yourappname>.apk"'); 
exit(file_get_contents('cric.apk')); }
header("Location: https://<yoursitename>.com/<yourfolder>/<yourappname>.apk"); 
exit();
?>
```

Add the following line in your .htaccess file. You can also create a new .htaccess inside that particular folder

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk
```

This adds the android apk mime-type.

Now users can navigate to https://yoursitename.com/yourfolder and install the apk.